# Selenium Search By label

Tags: java, selenium

i am working on a automatisation project , my problem is clear:
Instead of finding elements by(xpath and id) , my supervisor wants me to locate elements by ther label names:
Exemple :
User

```
<form id="loginForm" novalidate="" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="username" data-i18n="label.user">User</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="<username>" title="name.." d="username">
    <span class="help-block small">Your unique username to client</span>
</div>
```

The idea is the user will only tell me to put my username "xxx" into the label "User", and **i have to find the input of that label**.
Is there a way please? to find the input of a given label in selenium? (i am using java)

Comment: If you are going to locate an element by text contained in another element, you will have to use XPath... there is no other way. What have you tried? Where is your code or locator attempts?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty common in automation. you can locate the input field based on its label. you can apply the following logic to most fields.

**This is in Python.**

```
myinput = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'User')]/following::input[1]")
myinput.send_keys("you text")
```

Comment: thank you it worked , but i got the bigest problem in my project which i cant find a solution since 2months, look my project is a robo automatisation which SHould work on ANY site , the problem i need to develop a function "SearchInFrames" which is suppose to look into all the frames of a web page , and find the element i am looking for . but a web page can contains INFINITE numbers of frames (frame1,frame 2 ,frame3...) and each frame can contain another frames (frame1.1,frame1.2 ....) , so i need a RECURSIVE method which is able to look into all the frames until find the element

Answer (score 1):

Find **label** by text, get first parent **div** and get input inside the **div**

```
//label[.='User']/ancestor::div[1]/input
```

Same as previous with removing spaces in the **label** text

```
//label[normalize-space(.)='User']/ancestor::div[1]/input
```

Find **div** with child **label** by text and get **input** inside the **div**

```
//div[./label[.='User']]/input
```

Comment: thank you it worked , but i got the bigest problem in my project which i cant find a solution since 2months, look my project is a robo automatisation which SHould work on ANY site , the problem i need to develop a function "SearchInFrames" which is suppose to look into all the frames  of a web page , and find the element i am looking for .  but a web page can contains INFINITE numbers of frames (frame1,frame 2 ,frame3...) and each frame can contain another frames (frame1.1,frame1.2 ....) , so i need a RECURSIVE method which is able to look into all the frames until find the element

Comment: If this answer or any other one solved your issue, you can upvote answer and mark it as accepted, [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)